# How do I Remove the Very Last Letter in a Line of Letters

Tags: python, while-loop

I am having a bit of trouble removing one extra letter that is constantly popping up in my two lines, after my program evaluated all the numbers.

**What it Should Produce:**

How many steps did Nick take forwards:  4

How many steps did Nick take backwards:  2

How many steps did Bill take forwards:  5

How many steps did Bill take backwards:  3

How many steps were needed to finish the game:  13

Nick
FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 5 paces from the start

Bill
FFFFFBBBFFFFF = 7 paces from the start

Bill is Ahead after 13 steps

**What it Does Produce:**

How many steps did Nick take forwards:  4

How many steps did Nick take backwards:  2

How many steps did Bill take forwards:  5

How many steps did Bill take backwards:  3

How many steps were needed to finish the game:  13

Nick
FFFFBBFFFFBBFB = 5 paces from the start

Bill
FFFFFBBBFFFFFB = 7 paces from the start

Bill is Ahead after 13 steps

In the grand scheme of things, this issue isn't a huge deal, as the rest of the program works fine, but if anyone has a solution for this, I am all ears.

**My Code:**

```
#Enter how many steps Nick and Bill went forward and backward, and how many paces are needed to finish the game
A = int(input("How many steps did Nick take forwards: "))
B = int(input("How many steps did Nick take backwards: "))
C = int(input("How many steps did Bill take forwards: "))
D = int(input("How many steps did Bill take backwards: "))
S = int(input("How many steps were needed to finish the game: "))

#Counters to track how far Nick and Bill go, and how many paces they made to finish the game
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
paces = 0
paces2 = 0

#Check how many steps Nick and Bill made, and how many paces he took
print("\nNick")
while(counter < S):
  F = 0
  while(F < A):
    print("F", end="")
    F = F + 1
    paces = paces + 1
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= S:
      break
  b = 0
  while(b < B):
    print("B", end="")
    b = b + 1
    paces = paces - 1
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= S:
      break
print(" =",paces + 1 ,"paces from the start")     

#Check how many steps Bill made, and how many paces he took
print("\nBill")
while(counter2 < S):
  F2 = 0
  while(F2 < C):
    print("F", end="")
    F2 = F2 + 1
    paces2 = paces2 + 1
    counter2 = counter2 + 1
    if counter2 >= S:
      break
  b2 = 0
  while(b2 < D):
    print("B", end="")
    b2 = b2 + 1
    paces2 = paces2 - 1
    counter2 = counter2 + 1
    if counter2 >= S:
      break
print(" =",paces2 + 1 ,"paces from the start") 

#Display who won, and by how much
if paces > paces2:
  print("\nNick is Ahead after",S,"steps")
elif paces < paces2:
  print("\nBill is Ahead after",S,"steps")
elif paces == paces2:
  print("\nBill and Nick are Tied after",S,"steps")
```

Comment: Just a note that the problem statement is great, however in interests of time, you probably want to provide a more minimal example of the problem. I had a look and it looks like the title in the question actually sums it up the best.

Comment: A couple helpful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953).

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use counters for the number of steps and you have a break statement **after** you print the values and increment the counter.

You should move it **before**.

You error is a very classical [**off-by-one** error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) ;)

change:

```
  while(F < A):
    print("F", end="")
    F = F + 1
    paces = paces + 1
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= S:
      break
```

into:

```
  while(F < A):
    if counter >= S:
      break
    print("F", end="")
    F = F + 1
    paces = paces + 1
    counter = counter + 1
```

**And the same in 3 other occurrences of the similar loops.**

NB. I take the opportunity to tell you that while the logic of your code is good, you have a lot of repetitive code. Almost the same for both kids and for each kids almost the same for forward and backward.

What you should try to do now is to **refactor** your code to avoid duplicated logic. You could for example use a master loop to loop over the kids and forward/backward or better **use functions** to break your code into atomic tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You loop `while counter < S`

At the end of two cycles, you have `counter = 12`, and the outer loop starts again.

Now, you take one step forward, realize that `counter >= S`, and break out of the inner `while F < A` loop. But you still go into the next `while b < B` loop *before* you check the value of `counter`.

Instead, you should check the value of the `counter` as a condition for both inner loops, *before* you take a step in the inner loop.

```
A, B, S = 4, 2, 13
print("\nNick")
while(counter < S):
  F = 0
  while F < A and counter < S:
    print("F", end="")
    F = F + 1
    paces = paces + 1
    counter = counter + 1
    
  b = 0
  while b < B and counter < S:
    print("B", end="")
    b = b + 1
    paces = paces - 1
    counter = counter + 1
    
print(" =",paces + 1 ,"paces from the start")
```

which gives:

```
Nick
FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 6 paces from the start
```